# How to load numpy array in a tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to create a Dataset object in tensorflow 1.14 (I have some legacy code that i can't change for this specific project) starting from numpy arrays, but everytime i try i get everything copied on my graph and for this reason when i create an event log file it is huge (719 MB in this case).

Originally i tried using this function "tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()", but it didn't work, then i read it is a common problem and someone suggested me to try with generators, thus i tried with the following code, but again i got a huge event file (719 MB again)

```
def fetch_batch(x, y, batch):
    i = 0
    while i < batch:
        yield (x[i,:,:,:], y[i])
        i +=1

train, test = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
images, labels = train  
images = images/255

training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(fetch_batch, 
    args=[images, np.int32(labels), batch_size], output_types=(tf.float32, tf.int32), 
    output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape(features_shape), tf.TensorShape(labels_shape)))

file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/content", graph=tf.get_default_graph())
```

I know in this case I could use tensorflow_datasets API and it would be easier, but this is a more general question, and it involves how to create datasets in general, not only using the mnist one.
Could you explain to me what am i doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Can you explain a bit more in detail what's causing your event file to be that large? Is it creating repetitive subgraphs?

Comment: Could you explain what didn't work with `from_tensor_slices`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it's because you are using `args` in `from_generator`. This will surely put the provided `args` in the graph.

What you could do is define a function that will return a generator that will iterate through your set, something like (haven't tested):

```py
def data_generator(images, labels):
  def fetch_examples():
    i = 0
    while True:
      example = (images[i], labels[i])
      i += 1
      i %= len(labels)
      yield example
  return fetch_examples
```

This would give in your example:

```py
train, test = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
images, labels = train  
images = images/255

training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator(images, labels), output_types=(tf.float32, tf.int32), 
    output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape(features_shape), tf.TensorShape(labels_shape))).batch(batch_size)

file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/content", graph=tf.get_default_graph())
```

Note that I changed `fetch_batch` to `fetch_examples` since you probably want to batch using the dataset utilities (`.batch`).

Comment: Yes, i think you are right. I was about to post right now how i solved the problem (actually i found a guy in github who was suggesting this) and it worked for me

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14053

Thank you!

Comment: Cool, if this solution works then please accept it. Also, next time for your question, try to provide a code that can work if copy-pasted and include the version numbers (typically for tensorflow, the API changes a lot between 1.14 and 2.0).

Comment: Done, but one more thing: what do you mean with "you won't be able to use multiprocessing"?
Is there any more efficient way?

Comment: Actually forget what I said, you don't need multiprocessing at this stage (just getting the data), so I was completely confused.